# Is it possible to create a hyperlink from an \includegraphics picture?

Tags: graphics, hyperref, links

I'd like to make an image clickable, meaning I want to turn it into a hyperlink. I am including the image via `\includegraphics` but I am not sure how to make it clickable. Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: Which kind of action do you want to associate with the click?

Answer (score 7):

use `\href[options]{URL}{\includegraphics{...}}`